# Passportjs Facebook login flow (passport-facebook vs passport-token)

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport.js

Working with Node, Express, and Passport.

Okay, so my team and I are building a REST API for a dual-sided marketplace type application. We have already set up a basic LocalStrategy for email and password login.

**We want to make the API user-agent agnostic, so we can use the API via web, Android, or iOS.**

But where we are getting confused is with the FB login flow. The question is, what exactly goes on behind the scenes in Passportjs. We have looked into the 'passport-facebook' and 'passport-facebook-token' strategies, and can't really decide which one to go with.

This is my current understanding of the flow:

[image: Passport-token]

[image: Passport-facebook]

If this is correct, am I better off having the client get the access_token from FB then sending it to me, or just letting FB handle it via redirects and the callback URL?

Passport-token:

```
passport.use('facebook-token', new FacebookTokenStrategy( {
    clientID: 'xxx',
    clientSecret: 'xxx'
}, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // asynchronous
    //console.log("into passport auth");
    process.nextTick(function() {
        User.findOne({'facebook.id': profile.id}, function(error, user) {
            console.log("user is " + JSON.stringify(user));
            console.log("profile is " + JSON.stringify(profile));

            //do user creation stuff etc.

            return done(error, user);
        });
    });
}));

authRouter.post('/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook-token'), function (req, res) {
    console.log("into controller");
    if (req.user){
        //log the user in since they successfully authenticated with facebook.
        req.login(user);
        res.status(200).end();
    } else {
        res.status(401).end();
    }
});
```

Passport-facebook:

```
passport.use('facebook', new FacebookStrategy( {
    callbackURL: "http://75.128.65.176:8080/auth/facebook/callback",
    clientID: 'xxx',
    clientSecret: 'xxx'
}, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // asynchronous
    //console.log("into passport auth");
    process.nextTick(function() {
        User.findOne({'facebook.id': profile.id}, function(error, user) {
            console.log("user is " + JSON.stringify(user));
            console.log("profile is " + JSON.stringify(profile));

            //do user creation stuff etc.

            return done(error, user);
        });
    });
}));

// Redirect the user to Facebook for authentication.  When complete,
// Facebook will redirect the user back to the application at
//     /auth/facebook/callback
authRouter.get('/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

// Facebook will redirect the user to this URL after approval.  Finish the
// authentication process by attempting to obtain an access token.  If
// access was granted, the user will be logged in.  Otherwise,
// authentication has failed.
authRouter.get('/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/',
                                  failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

Any details/elaboration on how this flow actually works would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: I found these examples very useful

https://github.com/philipbrack/express-passport-facebook-token-example (server) and https://github.com/philipbrack/express-passport-facebook-token-example-client (client)

Answer (score 6):

> Verify if the 2 flows shown are correct.

Yes, they are correct.

---

> Q: I have a list of APIs. How can I protect them with passport-facebook strategy

You have serveral options:

### 1. Validate the `Facebook token`

- Server returns the `Facebook token` along with the user information
- Client sends `Facebook token` each time it calls an API
- Server validates the `Facebook token`

More information about how to validate `Facebook token` [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow).

### 2. Using JSON Web Token (JWT)

- Server returns a `JWT` after retreiving the Facebook user information
- Client sends `JWT` each time it calls an API
- Server validates the `JWT`

This way, the server does not have to send the request to Facebook to validate the `Facebook token`. More information [here](https://jwt.io).

---

> Q: If I'm using passport-facebook-token, how do I tell user to go and login on facebook

Your `/api/auth/facebook` only accepts `Facebook token` and returns corresponding `HTTP code`. Thus, asking the user to go and login in Facebook is the job of the client.

More information about how to create a Facebook login manually [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow).

Answer (score 5):

The client side Facebook redirects are inconvenient when using native iOS and Android Facebook SDKs - as they sometimes redirect to the user installed Facebook app instead. Hence if you would like a really generic API then you should go with `passport-facebook-token`.