# passport-facebook-token vs passport-facebook

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport.js

For social authentication in node.js, I have seen a number of projects using the [passport-facebook-token](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-facebook-token) package instead of the default [passport-facebook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-facebook).
I am trying (and struggling) to understand the differences and benefits between these two packages - and how to choose one from the other. Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**THE ANSWER**

After a good bit of reading I believe I have understand (at least the basics), and am sharing here for the benefit of others:

- **passport-facebook** uses an **OAuth2 — Authorization Code Grant** flow
- **passport-facebook-token** uses an **OAuth2 — Implicit Grant** flow

See this great [article on oauth flows](https://medium.com/@robert.broeckelmann/when-to-use-which-oauth2-grants-and-oidc-flows-ec6a5c00d864) for details of each of these. Some diagrams of the flows customized for these specific libraries can be found in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065226/passportjs-facebook-login-flow-passport-facebook-vs-passport-token).

**GENERAL CONFUSION**

Something that has become obvious in doing this research, is that there is a lot of confusion around authentication best practices. It is not clear to many (maybe most) exactly when each of the different [PassportJS](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/) strategies (or flows) should be used.

**SOME CONCLUSIONS**:

- **Authorization Code Grant** is more secure than Implicit Flow, as it does not share the third party access token directly with the user-agent (often a web-browser). Despite many articles to the contrary, this *will work fine with SPA*s as long as the SPA has "dedicated server-side component", such as a [BFF-API](https://samnewman.io/patterns/architectural/bff/) (like the [nestjs-bff](https://github.com/ahrnee/nestjs-bff) I am trying to build... which is what started this whole line of investigation in the first place)
- **Implicit Grant** represents an increased security vulnerabilities due to exposing the access token directly to the user-agent (often a web-browser). Use cases include SPA apps where there is no server-side component. Recently, industry best practices have been trending away from Implicit Grant and towards Authorization Code Grant, without the client secret, but with PCKE (Proof Key Code Exchange)... but that is typically [recommended for native mobile apps, rather then SPAs](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/182873/why-isnt-pkce-encouraged-for-single-page-apps).

**MY NET TAKE-AWAY:**

*Use Authorization Code Grant (passport-facebook) over Implicit Grant (passport-facebook-token)* if you have any dedicated server-side component to your client.

**INVITATION TO CHIME IN!**

I hope that helps others who found themselves with the same questions as I had. If anyone sees any errors, omissions, or incorrect assumptions about what I have written, please chime in.

Comment: you should also use passport-facebook-token if you want to allow user registration via "login with facebook" on your api.

Comment: Passport.JS link is broken